# Broadcast Receiver issue

Tags: java, android

Ok, so I have an app that needs to receive incoming SMS, and send out an SMS to the sender. This I can set up fine. The problem is, I only want the Broadcast Receiver to receive when the service is started. I declared the receiver class within the service. I destroy the reference (and unregister the receiver) in onDestroy. While the app compiles, and runs, the broadcast receiver never runs. If I delcare it in the manifest, it works fine, but never stops. The receiver just keeps waking up and processing.

Comment: I think it is because of something wrong when you register the broadcast receiver in your code. Could you paste the relevant code here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to implement this code:

```
<receiver android:name=".mystuff" android:enabled="false">
```

on

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName(context, mystuff.class),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

off

```
... PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to mention is that you need to declare the Receiver file in your manifest for sure. This actually registers your service with the phone. According to [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle)

> *A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.*

So what i have done is i defined my onReceive(Context, Intent) within the Service and register it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did that, but I didn't ALWAYS want it to receive. The solution BrainCrash suggested worked great however.